# Thread is terminated for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

So I am currently making a system to list all visible windows and then choose a random one. The code exists and is working.. in 32-bit. The problem is that it won't work when compiling for 64-bit. It does not even hit my breaking point before terminating the thread. I have also tried using a try block with the same result. The thread exit code is 0. NOTE: The code is messy due to it being filled with debugging and testing stuff.

Here is my code:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    wchar_t wnd_title[2048]; // Will be replaced
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(wnd_title), (LPARAM)wnd_title);

    if (!hwnd || !IsWindowVisible(hwnd) || !SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(wnd_title), (LPARAM)wnd_title)) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    
    std::vector<HWND>& Windows = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<HWND>*>(lParam);
    Windows.push_back(hwnd);

    OutputDebugString(wnd_title);
    OutputDebugString(L"\n");

    return TRUE;
}

std::vector<HWND> GetOpenWindows() {
    std::vector<HWND> Windows;
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&Windows));
    return Windows;
}

void GetRandomWindow() {
    stringstream ss;    // For Debug
    std::ostringstream stream;  //For Debug

    std::vector<HWND> Windows = GetOpenWindows();
    int ChosenWindow = Utils::RandIntRange(0, Windows.size());

    if (ChosenWindow < Windows.size()) {    // Breaking point here (HIT)
        TCHAR wnd_title[MAX_PATH];
        SendMessage(Windows[ChosenWindow], WM_GETTEXT, MAX_PATH, (LPARAM)wnd_title);    //Breaking point here (NOT HIT)
        OutputDebugString(L"\n");
        OutputDebugString(wnd_title);
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Hi", L"Test", MB_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are lying to `WM_GETTEXT` about the size of the buffer. `sizeof(wnd_title)` is the size in bytes, while the message expects the size in characters.

Comment: That fixed the issue of the thread terminating. But now the line int ChosenWindow = Utils::RandIntRange(...); is never hit. And the code gets stuck when listing all the windows in EnumWindowsProc. (to first comment)

Comment: Check usage of `sizeof()`.   I suspect you'll find that all usages of `sizeof(wnd_title)` need to be replaced by `sizeof(wnd_title)/sizeof(*wnd_title)`.

Comment: There's probably a hung window not responding to messages. Try `SendMessageTimeout`. Or use `GetWindowText` - it's guaranteed not to hang (but may return stale text).

Comment: The bane of Systems Hungarian:  when the prefix **lies** because it no longer matches the type.  And fixing it would be too painful, because it would break many things.  I much prefer Simonyi's Apps Hungarian or Apple's MacApp Hungarian, rather than MSDN's Systems Hungarian (popularized by Petzold).

Comment: Igor was right. A window was not responding to the messages! It now works like magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread was terminated because the wrong size was passed to the message. The thread hang issue was fixed by using `SendMessageTimeout(...);` instead of `SendMessage(..);`. This works because a window was not responding to any messages.

(Answer is for people who have the same issue)

Thanks to [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) and [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) for the help!